# Exporting DNNRegressor model to Cloud ML

Tags: tensorflow, google-cloud-ml

I'm trying to use the operation:

> tf.contrib.learn.DNNRegressor.export(*args, **kwargs)

to create the export.meta file required for Google Cloud ML uploading.
I've searched through the documentation (and Google) but didn't find a single practical example.

I wrote a very simple regressor that approximates the sum between two numbers (smaller than one):

```
# training data
def input_fn(size):
    A, B, R = [], [], []
    for x in range(size):
        a, b = random.random(), random.random()
        A.append(a)
        B.append(b)
        R.append(a + b)
    feature_cols = {'A': tf.constant(A, shape=[size, 1]),
                    'B': tf.constant(B, shape=[size, 1])}
    labels = tf.constant(R, shape=[size, 1])
    return feature_cols, labels

# regressor
FEATURES = ['A', 'B']
feature_cols = [tf.contrib.layers.real_valued_column(k) for k in FEATURES]
regressor = tf.contrib.learn.DNNRegressor(feature_columns=feature_cols, 
                                          hidden_units = [5, 3, 2],
                                          model_dir=MODEL_PATH)

# training
regressor.fit(input_fn=lambda: input_fn(1000), steps=5000)

#export
regressor.export(....
```

Everything works fine, but I was unable to build the input and output mappers required by the export function.
When uploading to Cloud ML, I got errors like:

> Model metagraph does not have outputs collection.

Thanks!

Comment: The documentation is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42407176/exporting-dnnregressor-model-to-cloud-ml, but just as a heads up, you should used SavedModel as we're about to make that the only supported format (https://tensorflow.github.io/serving/serving_basic.html)

Comment: I think you made a mistake when pasting the first documentation links, it redirect to this question.